# Cylindrical parameterization

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

Let S be the surface defined by the plane $$y+z=2$$ whose sides are the cylinder $$x^2+y^2 = 1$$Find the parameterization of the elliptical surface in cylindrical coordinates.
Sorry about the non mathjax equations, but I'm kind of new here and I need some quick help.[The problem as it appears on the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq9sX.png)

Comment: MathJax is not hard to learn for equations such as these.... why is the help needed quickly, I wonder?

Comment: Doh. Sorry for the edit override. It was not intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the projection of the ellipse on the $XY$-plane is the (bidimensional) disk $x^2 + y^2\le 1$. You can parametrize the disk using polar coordinates. An the equation $y + z = 2$ gives the third coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\phi(\theta,z)=(\cos{\theta},\sin{\theta},2-\sin{\theta})$$